# why it's called entryComponents in Angular Modules?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, angular-module

I just wonder why it's called entryComponents (when I need to instantiate a component imperatively), I just don't realize how the word `entry` relates to this ...

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components):
"A bootstrapped component is an entry component that Angular loads into the DOM during the bootstrap process (application launch). Other entry components are loaded dynamically by other means, such as with the router."

so the "entry" refers to the fact, that they are be the first component your app loads at startup or on routing. (Other components will be loaded *by* the entry components later)

Comment: Yes, it's just I had a problem with the word `entry`, may be it should be named like `dynamicallyReferencedComponents` not `entryComponents` or something that shows the real need of that attribute ...

Comment: I can see your point, but I think it is not always the case. The Bootstrapped component _is an entry component_, but it is not _dynamically_ referenced, as you hard-code it in the app.module.ts